# use a variable in the between php sql wordpress

Tags: php, database, wordpress, foreach, xampp

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php
$num = 2020-10-21;
$num = $_POST['subject'];
echo $num;
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wpsk_youtube_programs WHERE rating_date = . $num . ");
foreach ($results as $key => $program) { ?>
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<form name="form" action="" method="post">
<input type="date" name="subject" id="subject" value="<?php echo date('2020-10-21'); ?>"  />
 <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

here I am doing that get the date from the input field and store it on a variable ($num)
and now I want to pass this variable in the condition where I was fetching data from the data base so every time when anybody select a date and click on submit button so he can able to see the record of that day (from database)

Comment: what is your question ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['subject'])){
        $num = $_POST['subject'];
        echo $num;
        global $wpdb;
        $results = $wpdb->$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wpsk_youtube_programs WHERE rating_date = . $num . ");
        foreach ($results as $key => $program) { ?>
// Do your stuff
<?php
}
        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$results = $wpdb->$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wpsk_youtube_programs WHERE rating_date = '".$num."'");
```

Comment: Please, provide an explanation about your answer, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer